# jQuery.parseJSON not working for JsonResult from MVC controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery.parseJSON to parse out the return value from an MVC3 controller action.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        .. do stuff ..

        if (errors.Count() < 0)
        {
            return Json(new object[] { true, model, errors });

        }

        return Json(new object[] { false, model, errors });
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    var test = jQuery.parseJSON(data);                      
                }   
            });
```

Json result from fiddler:

> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> [false,{"UserName":"1","Password":"2","RememberMe":false},[{"Key":"","Errors":[{"Exception":null,"ErrorMessage":"The
>   user name or password provided is incorrect."}]}]]

Fiddler can parse the results:

[image]

The call to jQuery.parseJSON is returning null.
My questions is, how can I parse the json return value into an object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call parseJSON in your success handler, because `ajax` will have already parsed the JSON result (it does this automatically because you specified `dataType:'json'`) into your array.

However, I'd recommend returning some sort of result object (whether you create an actual class in C# or use an anonymous type).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        .. do stuff ..

        if (errors.Count() < 0)
        {
            return Json(new { success=true, model, errors });

        }

        return Json(new { success=false, model, errors });
    }
```

and at the client

```
$.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.success);
                    // also have result.model and result.errors                      
                }   
            });
```

Comment: The jQuery.parseJSON call still returns null.

Comment: ah... you don't need to parseJSON because `data` will already be an object. `ajax` will attempt to parse the JSON result, because you specified type dataType as json. parseJSON expects a string and you're giving it an object, hence the null return. I didn't pay careful attention to your question, sorry. I'll revise.

Comment: I see; let me play with this a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually returning an array of objects and they shoould be accessed like this in the success function:

```
var booleanValue = data[0];

var yourModel = data[1];

var yourErrors = data[2];
```

I did give @HackedByChinese an up vote because naming the properties might be a better way to go about it in the end. Howvbere this will solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @rboarman hmmmm...this is the correct syntax for reading your JsonResult `Json(new object[] { false, model, errors })` in your success method. Maybe there is a problem with the form. Why don't you try to change the `$.ajax()` call to a simple GET instead to work through the problem one step at a time.

Comment: @rboarman I've got a guess for you...does the `form` variable you are using in the `$.ajax()` call actually exist? Maybe you have a JS error you didn't notice. Can you make sure you have declared `var form = $("form:first");` just before the `$.ajax()` call which gets the first form in the document.